# How to add a custom button to the tinyMCE toolbar?

Tags: posts, tinymce

I want to add a custom button to the tinyMCE toolbar in the 'Add New Post' screen which when clicked, will insert text into the new post.

I have tried using this code (from http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/custom_toolbar_button.php):

```
wp_admin_css('thickbox');
wp_print_scripts('jquery-ui-core');
wp_print_scripts('jquery-ui-tabs');
wp_print_scripts('post');
wp_print_scripts('editor');
add_thickbox();
wp_print_scripts('media-upload');
setup : function(ed)
{
    // Add a custom button
    ed.addButton('mybutton', 
    {
        title : 'My button',
        image : 'img/example.gif',
        onclick : function() 
        {
        // Add you own code to execute something on click
        ed.focus();
        ed.selection.setContent('Hello world!');
        }
    });
}
```

but it fails to compile. It error's at the line with '**setup : function(ed)**'

Is it failing because I need to reference tinyMCE.js? I couldn't find that file under my WordPress installation on the server.

is there a better way of creating the button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem i believe are the lines that follow the enqueues and print scripts, you're mixing Javascript with PHP..

Javascript goes inside the HTML section of a PHP file or inside an echo statement.

[This page of the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Buttons) gives an example for adding a button to TinyMCE inside WordPress.

However that codex entry might be a bit dated, so in the event of problems with the code here are some alternative code samples to work from.

http://brettterpstra.com/adding-a-tinymce-button/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413470/how-to-add-a-mailto-button-to-tinymce

**RE: Code problems**

Inside a PHP file, HTML goes between the ending and starting PHP blocks, like so..

```
?>

<div>example</div>

<?php
```

Or alternatively inside an echo statement.

```
echo '<div>example</div>';
```

Javascript should be treated in the same manner as HTML, so you above code(the JS part) should look either like this..

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
setup : function(ed)
{
     // Add a custom button
     ed.addButton('mybutton', 
     {
          title : 'My button',
          image : 'img/example.gif',
          onclick : function() 
          {
          // Add you own code to execute something on click
          ed.focus();
          ed.selection.setContent('Hello world!');
     }
});
</script>
<?php
```

Or..

```
echo "
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
setup : function(ed)
{
     // Add a custom button
     ed.addButton('mybutton', 
     {
          title : 'My button',
          image : 'img/example.gif',
          onclick : function() 
          {
          // Add you own code to execute something on click
          ed.focus();
          ed.selection.setContent('Hello world!');
     }
});
</script>
";
```

The former being the easier approach in my opinion.

I hope that answers your question, and if you need help understanding something let me know..

Comment: I wasn't quite sure if i were actually addressing your opening question, but by the time i'd read the question back a second time i had the response written. Happy i was able to help in any case.. :)

Answer (score 2):

This here is the code I use in swift theme:

```
(function() {
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.tinyplugin', {

        init : function(ed, url){
            ed.addButton('note', {
            title : 'Insert a note',
                onclick : function() {
            var sel = ed.selection.getContent();
                    ed.execCommand(
                    'mceInsertContent',
                    false,
                    swift_notice(sel)
                    );
                },
                image: url + "/note.png"
            });
}

function swift_notice(seldata) {
    return '<p class="note"><span class="bg"> </span>'+ seldata + '</p>';
}
```