# Search/Replace for editor in HTML-mode

Tags: search, html, editor, customization

Is there a way to do a Search and Replace from the editor in HTML-mode?
Plugins I found work in the visual editor, we are working **only** in HTML-mode, therefore -not- appropriate for what we do.
I would appreciate to find a code snippet or plugin for HTML-mode (did I miss the one you found?)

Thanks in advance for time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a custom button with the functionality you require? You could attach a JavaScript method to do the search and replace as requested?

Check out:

[How to add a custom button to the tinyMCE toolbar?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6622/how-to-add-a-custom-button-to-the-tinymce-toolbar)

Hope this helps...

Comment: To create a btn is not such a problem(imho). Would appreciate to have the right function/code snippet. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Plugins like "Better search and Replace" will also allow you to search and replace HTML snippets very effectively. For example I wanted to remove the html chunk `<a name="more"></a>` and replace it `<br />` and the plugin executed it very efficiently...